# Лучший способ для смены букв "А" и "Б" местами

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Есть функция, которая принимает аргумент в виде строки, состоящей из "А", "а", "Б" и "б".

Каждая "Б" должна быть заменена на "А", каждая "А" на "Б" и так же с нижним регистром.

Пример:

```
>> swap('ААббББаа')
'ББааААбб'
```

Написал такой слабенький код, но рабочий:

```
def swap(text):
    new_text = []
    for c in text:
        if c == 'а':
            new_text.append('б')
        elif c == 'б':
            new_text.append('а')
        elif c == 'А':
            new_text.append('Б')
        elif c == 'Б':
            new_text.append('А')
    return ''.join(new_text)
```

Как можно решить эту задачу по другому, чтобы код был короче и/или быстрее?

Comment: В исходном коде вместо списка можно сразу использовать строку. Начинать с пустой и прибавлять по букве.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если важна скорость обработки, то рекомендую воспользоваться [translate](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
trantab = str.maketrans('АБаб', 'БАба')
text = 'ААббББаа'
print(text.translate(trantab))
```

Результат:

```
ББааААбб
```

Comment: Спасибо! Этот способ, видимо, самый лучший. Сделал так: `def swap(text): tab = str.maketrans('АБаб', 'БАба'); return text.translate(tab)`

Comment: @Николай, всегда пожалуйста. Мне кажется в данном случае нет особого смысла оформлять это как функцию, особенно если вы ее планируете часто вызывать, т.к. `str.maketrans()` есть смысл вызывать только раз для одинаковых наборов символов

Comment: @Николай: стоит заметить что `str.maketrans()` работает только для букв, которые одним символом (Unicode code point) представлены в строке (`'ё'` U+0435 U+0308 придётся нормализовать сперва). К примеру, чтобы Unicode смайлики в ascii преобразовать: `'smiling ☺  frowning ☹'.translate({ord('☺'): ':)', ord('☹'): ':('})` результат: `'smiling :)  frowning :('`. В обратную строну уже (2 символа  в 1) `str.translate()` не работает. Можно `"text :)".replace(":)", "☺")` использовать, результат: `'text ☺'`