# Как в Python заменить одну букву на другую?

Tags: python

Мне нужно заменить в словаре все 'І' на 'И', 'і' на 'и'. Как это можно сделать самым быстрым способом с точки зрения выполнения программы

```
data = {'Ін-5': 324,
        'іт': 21
        }
```

Comment: один из самых быстрых способов - [str.transalte](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616824/%d0%9b%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2-%d0%90-%d0%b8-%d0%91-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

при помощи [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) можно быстро заменить буквы, представленные одним символом (Unicode code point):

```
data = {'Ін-5': 324, 'іт': 21}

trantab = str.maketrans('Іі', 'Ии')

data = {k.translate(trantab):v for k,v in data.items()}

print(data)
```

---

результат:

```
{'Ин-5': 324, 'ит': 21}
```